# Crusader Kings 2: Capturing invader's lands?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My 82 years old king of a small kingdom got invaded by 8 years old nord king upstart.

I managed to defeat invader, killed all his troops, and "took over" all of his counties in the sense that I defeated defenders of every holding. All counties are now stripe-colored, and holdings have "under new administration icon".... except I can't have those counties.

If I "offer peace" there is no option take over counties or get any land. His casus belli was contesting one of my counties. He lost, so he didn't get it.

So... what now? Can I grab a bit of his land as a punishment for attacking me, or should I just end the war to cut the expenses? I don't see any option to actually get any land.

Or if I keep the war going for 10 years (I control everything, so he doesn't even spawn troops now) so the "under new administration" icon hopefully disappears, do I get those lands?

Advice?

Comment: Short answer - nope. You need to have a claim and on his lands and start a war yourself (which you obviously can't do if you are already at war) if you want to own new territory after the war.

Comment: EU IV has better peace mechanism than CK2. You negotiate the peace deal and impose conditions like forfeit of land, vassalization, complete annexation or imposing reparations on the loser, regardless of what the actual casus belli was and what was the defender in the war. The victor gets to dictate peace based on the war score. Wonder how long will it take for Paradox to implement that in CK2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are the defender then you can't get any land from winning the war, assuming he used claim CB. If you win, you gain some prestige and gold, while the loser loses the claim, some prestige and gold.

I don't think It might be worth prolonging the war if you are not a Nord, the "Levies are raised to long" stacks fast and take a long time to fade away, even after the war. If your vassals start rebelling and you are in the middle of a war, things can get bad really fast.

Answer (score 7):

Probably too late, but I think it's important to note that defenders do not suffer the "Vassal levies raised too long" relation penalty. As such, I would actually advise that you keep up the war for the time being.

Why? Because you should actually be getting a *bonus* to opinion with your vassals for "Defending against foreigners" or something like that. This could be extremely useful for when your 82 year old character dies, as the heir will inherit the war along with the relations bonus. This relations boost can be huge for mitigating the "Short Reign" penalty until it falls to manageable levels.

Edit: I suppose I should probably answer the overall question as well. No, there is no way to take land as the defender in CKII. However, as I pointed out, there are other ways to take advantage of being attacked.

Answer (score 4):

As the defender in the war you cannot gain land. He will lose Prestige (and possibly pay you gold depending on the CB) for losing the war. You should disband your levies and accept his surrender.

However, if you have any valid CB to press against him, you should do so immediately after the war ends. Truces are unidirectional, he may not attack you, but you are under no obligation to return the favor. Once the war ends his garrisons will begin reinforcing, but they will be quite some time recovering. For the next year or three his armies will be small, so winning another war against him will be trivial unless he gets outside help.

Comment: Assuming your levees aren't completely decimated too!

Comment: The upshot is that your holdings *will* be regenerating levies while the attacking Norge king *won't* reinforce levies in any occupied holding. So if SigTerm has literally occupied every holding of every county, they will have exactly 0 levies when the war ends. Since they can't raise any new levies, you could safely dismiss all of your armies to cut the maintenance and opinion penalties - holdings will remain captured and warscore will sit at 100%. Be wary if the attacker has unwed family members, as this could quickly gather them a new ally and army to flip the war back the other way.